# Find probability for distribution of several random variable

Tags: statistics

let $f(x,y)=k$ if $x >0, y>0, x+y <3$ and $0$ otherwise. Find $k$, find $P(x+y \leq 1), P(Y>X)$

I know that $0 <y<3-x$ but I also need to find the upper bound of $x$ in order to do th integrate to find $F(x,y)$ then find $k$. I wonder if anyone would tell me how to find it.

I know how to find $P(a<X<b,c<Y<d)$ but I'm not sure I know how to find $P(Y>X)$ and I can't find any example of this kind of problem in the book. I would be appreciate if you can explain this too me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your domain you have three frontiers $x=0$, $y=0$ $x+y=3$ therefore if you fix $y$ to be between $0$ and $3-x$,  $x$ is moving between $0$ and $3$. Therefore you have a triangle of area equal to $\frac{9}{2}$ and then $k=\frac{2}{9}$.

To find the probability of $P(Y>X)$ you could find the conditional probability or look in your graph the domain defined between the triangle and the upper region of $y=x$ and then:

$$\int_0^\frac{3}{2}\int_x^{3-x}kdydx$$

Which by simmetry of the distribution must be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: for the inner integral I got it bounded from $0$ to $3-y$ and got $\frac{1}{2}$ as result.

Comment: @drhab thanks now is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut for finding $P\left\{ Y>X\right\} $:

As always we have:

(1) $1=P\left\{ Y>X\right\} +P\left\{ X=Y\right\} +P\left\{ X>Y\right\} $

Next to that it can be shown in this case that:

(2) $P\left\{ Y>X\right\} =P\left\{ X>Y\right\} $ (consequence of $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ everywhere)

(3) $P\left\{ X=Y\right\} =0$

These three facts lead to $P\left\{ Y>X\right\} =\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: is that (2) and (3) applied in this case because we have $x>0$ and$y>0$ in the first place?

Comment: (2) is purely a direct consequence of $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for each pair $(x,y)$. That tells us that $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have exactly the same distribution. (3) is always true if the distribution of $(X,Y)$ has a PDF.

Comment: thank you very much, this is really a shortcut. :D

Comment: You are very welcome.